# Perl: How to search a file named ".cfg" in a directory and all it's parent directories

Tags: perl

How to search a file named ".cfg" in a directory and all it's parent directories
I am fetching the name as below code but i would like to know if there is any better way to do it.
Also i would like to know the recursive way to do the same.

```
sub get_p4_config_updir($ $)
{
  my ($client_root, $cfg_file) = @_;
  # Dir from where search starts - it's a client root here
  my $cur_dir = $client_root;
  printf("**** cur_dir: $cur_dir ****\n");
  my $slashes = $cur_dir =~ y/\///;
  printf("**** no of back slashes: $slashes ****\n");
  while($slashes > 2) {
     my ($parent_dir, $b) = $cur_dir =~ /(.*)\/(.*)/;
     printf("**** parent_dir: $parent_dir, b: $b ****\n");
     $slashes--;
     if (-e "$cur_dir/$cfg_file") {
        printf("**** File exists in dir: $cur_dir ****\n");
        return $cur_dir;
     }
     $cur_dir = $parent_dir;
  }
  return "";
}

my $cfg = '.cfg';
my $dir = '/user/home/wkspace/abc/def/MAIN';
my $path = get_p4_config_updir($dir, $cfg);
if ($path ne "") {
  printf("**** File exists in dir: $path ****\n");
} else {
  printf("**** File not found ****\n");
}
```

Comment: `return $dir_root/$cfg_file` - To be clear about the problem, Perl sees that as a division sum.

Comment: `$cur_dir == $parent_dir` - That will almost always be try. You need to use `eq` instead of `==`  to compare strings.

Comment: Instead of manipulating paths with regular expressions, it would be far clean an easy if you do it using [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) (or even the older [File::Spec](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec))!

Answer (score 4):

An example using [`Path::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use Path::Tiny;

# Returns a Path::Tiny object to the directory containing the file
# being looked for, or undef if not found.
sub get_p4_config_updir {
    my ($client_root, $cfg_file) = @_;
    my $dir = path($client_root)->realpath;
    while (1) {
        # say "Looking at $dir";
        if ($dir->child($cfg_file)->exists) {
            return $dir;
        } elsif ($dir->is_rootdir) {
            return undef;
        } else {
            $dir = $dir->parent;
        }
    }
}

my $cfg = '.cfg';
my $dir = '/user/home/wkspace/abc/def/MAIN';
say get_p4_config_updir($dir, $cfg) // "File not found";
```

---

Or a version that's similar to @rajashekar's idea of walking the directory tree by using `chdir` to get each directory's parent. This one uses [`File::chdir`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::chdir), which lets you `local`ize changes to the current working directory (and restores the original when the function/scope exits), as well as providing a handy array view of the current directory and its parents that can be manipulated:

```perl
use File::chdir;

...

sub get_p4_config_updir {
    my ($client_root, $cfg_file) = @_;
    local $CWD = $client_root; # Magic happens here
    while (1) {
        # say "Looking at $CWD";
        if (-e $cfg_file) {
            return $CWD;
        } elsif ($CWD eq "/") {
            return undef;
        } else {
            pop @CWD; # CDs to the next parent directory
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use core libraries to do this in a platform independent, readable way without having to use `cwd` and possibly causing action at a distance effects in the rest of your code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec::Functions qw(catfile rel2abs updir);

sub get_p4_config_updir
{
    my ($dir, $file) = @_;
    $dir = rel2abs($dir);

    do {
        my $path = catfile $dir => $file;
        return $dir if -e $path;

        return if $dir eq (my $new_dir = rel2abs(catfile $dir, updir));
        $dir = $new_dir;
    } while ('NOT_DONE');

    return;
}

sub main {
    my ($cfg, $dir) = @_;

    my $path = get_p4_config_updir($dir, $cfg);

    if (defined $path) {
        printf("Found '%s' in '%s'\n", $cfg, $path);
    }
    else {
        printf(
            "Did not find '%s' in '%s' or any of its parent directories\n",
            $cfg,
            $dir,
        );
    }
}

main(@ARGV);
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Temp> perl p.pl linux.bin .
Found 'linux.bin' in 'C:\'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why deal with pathnames, when you can walk the directory structure up with `..` ?

- if the file exists in the current directory return it.
- else go up `..` and the repeat the process.

```
use Cwd qw(cwd);

sub search_up {
  my ($dir, $file) = @_;
  chdir($dir);

  while (1) {
    if (-e $file) {
      print "$file exists in $dir\n";
      return $dir;
    } elsif ($dir eq "/") {
      return;
    } else {
      chdir("..");
      $dir = cwd;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: can not do "chdir" and "cwd" as i will be executing this piece of code from some other workspace or directory entirely.

Comment: Why not? You can store the initial working directory and restore it upon exit if your script is part of a bigger program.

Answer (score -1):

Please see if following code snippet complies with your requirements.

The script is looking for configuration file toward root of filesystem, found filenames are stored in an array `@found`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $dir = '/user/home/wkspace/abc/def/MAIN';
my $ext = 'cfg';

my($cwd,@found);

for( split('/',$dir) ) {
        $cwd .= "$_/";
        push @found, glob( $cwd . "*\.$ext" );
}

if( @found ) {
        say for @found;
} else {
        say 'No file(s) was found';
}

exit 0;
```

Following code snippet is looking for configuration files away from root filesystem starting from `$dir`.

If any files found then they will be stored under array reference `$found` and then printed out on the terminal.

If no files get found then you will be informed with a message.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $dir = '/user/home/wkspace/abc/def/MAIN';
my $ext = 'cfg';

my $found = find($dir,$ext);

if( $found ) {
    say for @$found;
} else {
    say 'No file(s) was found';
}

exit 0;

sub find {
    my $dir = shift;
    my $ext = shift;
    my $ret;
    
    for( glob("$dir/*") ) {
        push @$ret, $_ if /\.$ext\z/;
        if( -d ) {
            my $found = find($_,$ext);
            push @$ret, @$found if $found;  
        }
    }
    
    return $ret;
}
```